# JDBC Error in insert with DB2 (works with Sql Server)

Tags: jdbc, db2

I use in a Java Application JDBC to query the DBMS. The application works correctly with Sql Server but I get this error in DB2 during one insert:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=1, DRIVER=3.63.75

The insert is made using the `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`.

My query is a plain select of the table, then I declare my `PreparedStatement`, passing the parameters and afterwards with the `ResultSet` I do first the `moveToInsertRow()` and then the `insertRow()`.

Do you know if there are any problems with this approach using DB2?

As I told you before the same code works correctly with Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Code -302](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n302.dita) on DB2 means:

> THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE

So it seems like you are trying to insert a value into a column which is too large or too short (e.g. `Hello World` into a `varchar(5)`). Probably the column has a different length in DB2 and sql-server or you are inserting different values.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply, I've checked the table and they are identical. Also the data are correct because I take them from a call to a cobol routine with fixed fields (the fields are mapped in a cobol copy with fixed length).  I will try to change the insert without using the ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: @user3265189 Are there any special characters in the data you want to insert? Do you know which column causes this error? That are details which would be nice to know.

Comment: Hi, no there are no special characters, I've made the test I told you (i.e. without using ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE) and now it worked correctly ! Maybe the driver the client is using does not support this feature or there is an option to be added on the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to add to this thread.. but someone else might find it useful

Got the same SQL Exception when trying to do a `SELECT` : didn't realize the property value in `WHERE` clause was exceeding the limit on the corresponding column

```
SELECT * FROM <schema>.<table_name> WHERE PropertyName = 'value';
```

value was a `VARCHAR` type but exceeded the Length limit

Detailed exception does say it clearly that data integrity was violated: `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException`

So a good idea would be to do a length check on the value(s) that are being set on the properties before firing any queries to the database.